# NetLogo Counter Variable Incrementation

Tags: netlogo

---

My question involves setting a global counter variable.

Sample Code:

```
globals [counter]

to go
   ;if counter / 6 is a whole number (as in is divisible by 6)
   ask turtles
   [
      forward 1
   ]   
set counter counter + 1
   ;otherwise
   ask turtles
   [
      right 60
      forward 1
   ]
end
```

Assume I've set up turtles and patches accordingly already. The idea is how to get my counter variable to test for true/false on being divisible by a number.

Answer (score 4):

do you want the counter to increment each timestep? If so, use ticks instead as suggested by bergant instead of counter. Use counter if you are going to introduce some code later that means the counter only increments on some timesteps. I have also taken out your comment markers so the movement happens.

If using counter:

```
globals [counter]

to go
  ask turtles
  [ ifelse counter mod 6 = 0
    [ forward 1 ]
    [ right 60
      forward 1 ]
  ]
  set counter counter + 1
  ...
  tick
end
```

If using ticks:

```
to go
  ask turtles
  [ ifelse ticks mod 6 = 0
    [ forward 1 ]
    [ right 60
      forward 1 ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: Missing `ask turtles`?

Comment: yes! thanks nicolas. i had some other lines in while i was testing and deleted too many

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ticks` (reports the current value of the tick counter).

Use [`reset-ticks`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reset-ticks) to set the counter to zero (this also updates all plots) - usually in your setup procedure.

Call `tick` to increment the ticks (go procedure)

And use [mod](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/mod.html) operator for modulo.