# How to delay a turtle variable for X number of ticks?

Tags: variables, time, delay, netlogo, lag

I am looking to delay my turtle variable [individual-power].
When [individual-power] reaches 15, I would like it to wait (or gradually climb) to 100 over 20 ticks. Currently, with each tick [indivdiual-power] decreases by one.

Does anyone know how to do this? Current code:

```
    to setup-turtles
    create-turtles 40
    ask turtles
    [
    set color blue
    set shape "person"
    set size 1.7
    set individual-power 100
    set heading 90
    set solar-delay 0
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    ]
    end


    to go
    ask turtles [
    if individual-power >= 15
    [forward 1
    set label individual-power
    set individual-power individual-power - 1]

    if recharge-options = "external-solar" [solar-battery]
    ]
   tick
   end

   to solar-battery ;; how to make individual power take 20 clicks before jumping up to 100, but this doesn't show the time-delay I'm looking for
   if individual-power = 15
   [repeat 20 [set individual-power 15]
   set individual-power 100]
   end
```

Tried also another solar-battery code with a new [solar-delay] variable to help with timing (individual-power is low, then solar-delay will start counting, once solar-delay hits 20, individual-power will increase to 100).. but this doesn't quite work.

```
    to solar-battery ;; how to make individual power take 20 clicks before jumping up to 100
    if individual-power = 15
    [set solar-delay solar-delay + 1]

    if solar-delay = 20
    [set individual-power 100
    set solar-delay 0]
    end
```

Comment: It sounds like you want a counter- some variable that you can use to track the number of ticks (or whatever event) that have occurred since the counter began. Have a look at JenB's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478418/netlogo-counter-variable-incrementation) for a simple counter that may demonstrate what you need.

Comment: Thanks @LukeC! That makes sense, I just don't know if the "mod" function is the language I need. Trying to make something happen specifically when individual power (a turtle variable) hits the number 15.

Comment: ABC -No, probably not- you can just increment the counter (eg `set counter counter + 1` and then evaluate if it is the number you need (eg `if counter = 15 [ some action here]`